# How to distinguish between a data uri and an image url?

Tags: regex, image, url, uri

I have a php script that handles the url sent to it via ajax from a js file. This is either a data uri or an image url. What would be the best way to distinguish whether the string supplied is a data uri or an image url, from the php script. I was thinking of using a regex to test the data uri. But i dont seem to come with a right regex that can handle the data uri.

Answer (score 2):

Well... if it starts with `data:` then it's a data URL. So... `if( substr($url,0,5) == "data:")` should do it.

Remember: KISS.

Comment: I don't think that's what he means. Presumably `http://somewhere.com/foo.html` is data, `http://www.somewhereelse.net/bar.jpg` is image.

Comment: Well, of course that should do it, for now. I wonder why I was thinking of everything else but a simple substr.

Comment: @user2148105 Happens to the best of us! I can't tell you how many times I've scratched my head as to why some code wasn't working, only to find I'd written `$btns` instead of `$btn`!

Comment: @Kolink : Lol .. true! bdw,Any idea how you could get the file extension from the data? exploding the mime type based on the "/" delimiter seems a bit strange to me. Any other way how we can get the extension of the file from the data uri?

Comment: Nope - the mime-type tells us how the data is encoded, there is no filename and therefore no extension. Explode might not be the best option, though. Try another substr: `trim(substr($url,strlen("data:image/"),4),";,");` - this will get the piece right after the `image/`. The extra trim stuff is because it could be three letters (eg. png) or four (eg. jpeg), but it's always followed by `;` or `,` so you can just trim it off.

Comment: thats equivalent to exploding the type obtained from the $_FILE array ! well .. logically it should work fine for images. Will be using it for the time being. I am on the lookout for something foolproof though :P

Comment: > "if it starts with `data:` then it's a data URL." Not necessarily. Consider `username:password@example.com/index.html` where the username is set to `data`.

Answer (score 0):

Check the extension of the **URL**.

**Regex:**    `\.[^\.]*$`

Comment: I think checking the mime type from the header is a better practice than simply checking the extension.

Comment: @user2148105 yup, you're right.  Tried in javascript, looks clean.  Thanks for that.